# How can I test in-app-billing with a non-published app?

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I have an Android app that uses In-App-Billing to sell Account Managed Items.

I tested the app with the static response IDs and everything seems to work. I now want to test the app with real product Ids.

I created the app in the Google Play Store and uploaded a draft version of the app with the correct permissions. I now created an In-App-Billing item and published the item.

At the moment the app is unpublished. The item is created and published and I have a test account that is registered in the profile of the developer account and is the only account on the device that I use for testing.  The app is signed with the same key as the uploaded draft. **Edit:I'm testing with Android 4.1 && 4.03 at the moment**

If I try to buy the item the Google Play Store pops up but shows a dialog with the following method: **The item you requested is not available for purchase.**

How can I test buying the item without publishing the app?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing **In above link please read carefully all OR THIS PART >> "Instruct testers to make test purchases"** DRAFT APK'S not supported. Note: Previously you could test an app by uploading an unpublished "draft" version. This functionality is no longer supported. However, you can test your app with static responses even before you upload it to the Google Play Store. For more information, see Test with static responses. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

When you test the app, make sure you have exported and correctly signed it (not using debug key). Also make sure that you are using the correct Google account (registered test account) on the device.

Additionally, the registered test account **cannot** be the developer account.

Apart from this, it should work fine.

**Note:** Testing your own in-app purchases does require a valid credit card and actual payment.

And finally, it currently takes a few hours for market edits to propagate through the servers and show up.

Comment: Good point. Forgot to mention that I use the correctly signed App for testing

Answer (score 3):

For others who reach this thread, Now it's `not possible to test In-app billing with just a draft version` of the app.

> Draft Apps are No Longer Supported
>   Previously, you could publish a "draft" version of your app for testing. This functionality is no longer supported. Instead, there are two ways you can test how a pre-release app functions on the Google Play store:

- You can publish an app to the alpha or beta distribution channels. This makes the app available on the Google Play store, but only to the testers you put on a "whitelist".
- In a few cases, you can test Google Play functionality with an unpublished app. For example, you can test an unpublished app's in-app billing support by using static responses, special reserved product IDs that always return a specific result (like "purchased" or "refunded").

for details read https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-test

Answer (score 2):

It may take some time to reflect the changes on google play if you just uploaded the app and added the item there wait for some time near about 2 hr. it will be shown the item you want to purchase.

Comment: The app is over one week old. One of the items is published for some days. The other items are only active for an hour. I will try to buy them again later today.

Comment: items which were published some days ago are you able to buy them?
or only the item you added hours ago not showing?

Comment: I waited the whole weekend but the items published on friday and those published days ago are still not available for purchase.

Comment: what errors are you getting? and have you cross checked the id's you put on google play for your products with the purchasing item's id?

Answer (score 0):

You can test in-app billing by using options, look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html)

**Edit :**

On the link I mentionned, you can see this :

> Note: You do not need to publish your application to do end-to-end
>   testing. You only need to upload your application as a draft
>   application to perform end-to-end testing.

If you still can not test it, what you can do is to publish it and test it. If you think there might be bugs in your app's in-app billing, refunds are still a solution.

I'm thinking about something, on the dev site, you can see this :

> Verify that your device is running a supported version of the Google
>   Play application or the MyApps application.

On what Android version are you testing on ?

Comment: thx I know that page. Just posting a link is not very helpful and is not a contribution to the knowledge base of Stackoverflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer for more tips on how to answer questions.

Answer (score 0):

You've to add the products(item sku) in you app product in your play store app account. The `SKU` you set `In-App` billine is not available. For testing, set the `SKU`  `androidtestpayment`. Now you'll now get that error **The item you requested is not available for purchase.**